# how do i send an email with info from a row with criteria from one of its column using google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to write a script that will send an email based on the criteria of a single column.

This is for an inventory management system that will send emails to remind that certain items are low in count.

eg.
if row 5's column J is = "reminder", send values of row 5's column B and C to my email. (col B and C is item description and quantity count respectively)

I just started learning about google app script so I'm not sure how to write it myself, but from other forum posts, this is what I got.

```
var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues(); 
 
  values.forEach(function(row) {
    var indent = row[10]; //column j
   
  if (indent !== '') {
    
    var EditedRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("store list").getRange(indent); 
    var Edited = EditedRange.getValue();
    }

    // Fetch the email address
    var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("mail").getRange("B2");
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();
    // Send Alert Email.    
    var message = Edited; 
    var subject = 'For Action: Indent' ;
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);  
  });
  
 }
```

I split the code up and tested emailing and apparently the email portion of the codes work, but it is the retrieving of data that is not working and I don't really know how to get it working.

Comment: There are many examples of email scripts on this site.  I suggest you do a little more research

Answer (score 0):

- To get started, have a look at the [Apps Script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- There you will see that to retrieve the value of a single cell it is bets to use the method [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#getvalue) instead of `getValues()`
- You need to specify the range (cell) wrom ehre you want to get the value
- The easiest way to do so is with the method [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=en#getrangea1notation) specifying `A1` notation

A simple sample would be:

```js
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var checkValue = sheet.getRange("J5").getValue();
if (checkValue == "reminder"){
  var B5Value = sheet.getRange("B5").getValue();
  var C5Value = sheet.getRange("C5").getValue();
  var message = B5Value + " and " + C5Value;
  var emailAddress = "you need to define the email address of the recipient either in the code or a cell of the sheet";
  var subject = "Define here your subject";
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);  
}
```

Please make sure to dedicate enough time to study the Apps Script documentation to understand this code and be able to troubleshoot and perform simple modifications.